# Close all variable explorer windows in Spyder

Tags: python, window, spyder

Does anyone know of a quick way to close all open variable explorer windows in Spyder? (i.e. the windows that open when you click on a variable).

In Matlab, you can close all pop-up windows with `close all`. Does anything like that exist for Spyder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We don't have a command to do that, sorry.